# Display Order of Stationary Files in TeXShop

Tags: templates, texshop

The "*New from Stationary...*" menu option in TeXShop allows you to select the specific stationary to start of new `.tex` files. This is very useful when one needs to ensure consistency between files.

However, I am not able to figure out the order in which these stationary files are displayed. I have numerous similar files I start with, two of which that are used very often. Thus, it would be preferrable to have these displayed as the first two instead of in what appears to be some random postion:

[image]

#### Notes:

- TeXShop Version 4.73

#### Questions:

1. Is there a way I can control the display order? I attempted to rename the files so that they would show up in the desired order, but that does not appear to work.
2. If the answer to #1 is "no", then what is the algorithm that is used to determine the display order? Knowing what this is, may allow for a hack to get the files to be displayed in the desired order.

Comment: It used to be alphabetical but now it indeed does seem totally random.

Comment: I’d guess this is all done by the OS but there maybe some control that an be applied. Write to the author and let him know.

Comment: That looks like Stationary not Templates! Put a copy of those Stationary files (`~/Library/TeXShop/Stationary`) into the Templates folder (`~/Library/TeXShop/Templates`). You then Open a New Document and can pick a Template from the Templates popup menu (which IS alphabetical) in the Source Window Toolbar. You can open `~/Library/TeXShop` using the menu item under the TeXShop Menu.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: Yes I meant "Stationary" (did not know about "Templates" as I don't see a  "New from Template...". I see that I can open the "Open ~/Library/TeXShop" menu, but that just opens the folder. Thus, this process will open the acutal template file -- it will not create a new document with that template. Thus, the only way I can think of to using this is to copy and paste that into a new document -- otherwise I am changing the actual template.

Comment: @PeterGrill No, the Templates are accessible via the pulldown menu in any document window. So this could be used instead of the Stationery function. But I like the New from Stationery function, and I agree it would be nice to order the files in it.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Found the "Templates" option. I guess I had removed it along time ago as I was not using that functionality.  I agree, it is not quite as useful as the Stationary option -- at least for my purposes.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in TeXShop 4.77.

Comment: @PeterGrill I just came here to say the same thing. Maybe you should just make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is now fixed in TeXShop 4.77.

The same files from the  "*New from Stationary...*" are now displayed as

[image]